# Inside a React single-page app, what is a useful way to measure the time for a page to appear visually complete?

Tags: performance, reactjs

Or, if exact measurement is difficult, is there a measurement that will respond somewhat proportionally to front-end improvements? We'd like to fire an event when that happens (for Real User Monitoring).

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/perf.html

Comment: I kind of can't believe I've never seen this tool! It looks very useful, but for this we're trying to collect measurements on the production site. Thanks!

Comment: If you're looking for an APM, [AppDynamics](https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO43/End-User+Monitoring) has some pretty cool tools for these types of end-user metrics.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea that may give you what you need. I tried it and it does work, but I am not sure if this will be accurate enough for your needs.
I should also point out that I did not try this with nested components, but rather only regarding a single component with all of its markup. This will be clear from my code.

Some points must be prefaced before the approach. We know that in the react lifecycle the `constructor`is the first to fire and that `componentDidMount` fires right after the rendering of the component. This makes me think that the time it takes between the constructor to fire and componentDidMount to fire is the time it takes for the rendering to complete.

Another important point is the way `setTimeout` works. We know that the amount of time that gets passed to the setTimeout function is not the actual amount that it will take till the function will fire, but rather it is the minimum amount until the function will fire. This is because of the [event loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ&t=2s) and is beyond the scope here.

With the above in mind here is my code.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.timer();
  }

  timer() {
    let date = new Date();
    console.log(date.toLocaleTimeString())
    setTimeout(() => {
      myTimer();
    }, 0)

    function myTimer() {
      let date = new Date();
      console.log(date.toLocaleTimeString())
    }
  }

  createItems() {
    let items = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
      items.push(<h3 key={i}>{i}</h3>)
    }
    return items;
  }

  render() {
    const items = this.createItems();
    return (
      <div>
        {items}
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

The idea here is that since the constructor fires first I can call my timer function from there and get the starting time. Then in my timer function I call a setTimeout and pass it 0 as the delay parameter. Because JavaScript is single threaded the callback in setTimeout will only fire once the rendering is complete, therefor I pass it no delay to ensure that it does in fact fire right after the rendering is complete.  The callback function then logs the current time again, and I can now see the difference between start and end time of rendering.

Hope this helps.